# How to promote service calls over asset loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, asynchronous

We have an infinite scroll solution where we would like to load the elements into the DOM and have the  load lazily without blocking other more important calls.

We are using Angular, so are the modules at our disposal?

Does anyone have any suggestions or resources that we can use to combat this problem?

The goal is to have load images with less priority so that it doesn't block the service.

[image]